# Insert weight in kgs AND lbs in one cell?

Tags: google-sheets, formulas

Right now, a cell is showing the value:

```
10
```

I want it to show:

```
10 kg or 22 lbs
```

And I want that to happen in the same cell. 
Also, that `10` is also a result of a calculation `=B2-80`
I ended up using the `concat` formula a bunch of times.

Comment: @MARKMYANSWER I think that the last edit is inappropriate as the added sentence is part of an answer of the OP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- **`=B2-80&"kg or "&(B2-80)*2.2&" lbs"`**
- **`=JOIN("kg or "; B2-80; (B2-80)*2.2&" lbs")`**
- **`=CONCAT(B2-80&"kg or "; (B2-80)*2.2&" lbs")`**
- **`=CONCATENATE(B2-80; "kg or "; (B2-80)*2.2; " lbs")`**

  [image: 5]

  [image: 5]

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I ended up using the concat formula a bunch of times. Like so:

```
=CONCAT(B2-80,concat("kg",concat(" or ", concat((B2-80)*2.2," lb"))))
```